# How to make jira attachments download work using jira rest api

Tags: download, jira, attachment, jira-rest-api

I am trying to download attachments from Jira. I use /rest/api/2/attachment/{id} to get json response of the attachment. It has field "content" that is the attachment url. I use this url and construct HttpGet and execute to get response that always gives me html content asking for login. I am sending Basic Authorization in the httpGet header. Apparently this works for downloading .png files but not any other file types. I am using java spring rest to connect to Jira horizon.

```
Closeable httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(jira attachmenturl);
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic <base64Credentials>);
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet)
```

The response for .txt, .jpeg, Microsoft documents is different from response that I get for .png files.

Comment: can you share the complete code or how you downloaded the file?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getAttachment")
public String getAttachment(@RequestParam("id") String attachmentID) throws Exception {
    Client client = Client.create();
    
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(jiraBaseURLRest + "attachment/" +
    attachmentID);
    
    ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic " +
    base64Creds).type("application/json")
    .accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
    
    String result = response.getEntity(String.class); 
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
    System.out.println("JSON Object = "+jsonObj);
    URL url = new URL(jsonObj.getString("content"));
    
    Closeable httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
    httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
    CloseableHttpResponse response1 = ((CloseableHttpClient) httpclient).execute(httpGet);
    
    if(response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
    {
        HttpEntity entity = response1.getEntity();
        if (entity.isStreaming())
        { 
            System.out.println("Streaming..."); 
            byte data[] = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity); 
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://pdf1.pdf"));
            fout.write(data);
            fout.close();
            System.out.println("Done!!"); 
        }
    }
    
    return "Success";
}
```